# How to prove Binet theorem, namely $\det ( AB ) = \det (A ) \det ( B )$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've tried with the formulation of two arrays $2 \times 2$, but could not.

Comment: Have you tried looking up a proof? The usual proof is long (probably too long to expect an answer here) and uses "elementary matrices"

Comment: For this demonstration there is no "technical" way, like multiplying the elements of the matrix. You need to come back to the definition of determinant of a matrix, that is determinant of a linear application.

Comment: The case of $2\times 2$ matrices is not difficult.  Be more patient with the algebra and your efforts will succeed.

Comment: I don't agree with the closing of this question.  The two answers posted before it was closed both assume knowledge that a person encountering this identity for the first time would typically not have.  A better answer should be posted.

Comment: Since the $2\times2$ case is mentioned in the question, let's look at that.
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = ad-bc.
$$
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{bmatrix} = eh-fg.
$$
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ae+bg & af+bh \\  ce+dg & cf+dh \end{bmatrix}.
$$
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} ae+bg & af+bh \\  ce+dg & cf+dh \end{bmatrix} = (ae+bg)(cf+dh) - (ce+dg)(af+bh). \tag 1
$$
So one should expand and simplifty $(1)$ and one should multiply the first two determinants found above. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The space of multilinear alternating form defined on $M(n,R)$ has dimension 1 and is generated by the determinant. Fix $A$, consider $f(X)=\det(AX)$, it is a multilinear alternating form, so it is of the form $c\det(X)$, $f(I_n)=\det(AI_n)=c\det(I)=\det(A)=c$.

Comment: "alternat**ing** form"

Comment: Also, it is doubtful that someone encountering Binet's theorem for the first time will know what you mean when you say that "the determinant *generates* the *space* of *multilinear, alternating forms*.

Comment: Believe me or not, this is the first proof that I have learned

Comment: Found myself two proofs:

1) you can do by (reverse) induction on the numbers of colums of B that are vectors of the canonical base (must be all different otherwise B and AB have two equal columns and the theorem holds true)
If such number is n, then B is a permutation matrix and its determinant is its  sign while AB is the same permutation of the rows of A and its determinant is det A times this sign.
In general you can increase the number of canonical vectors among the columns of B by using linearness on the columns of B and Laplace formula and induction hipothesis.

Comment: 2) From direct definition: writing out the definition det A det B is the product of two sums (over permutations) of products of a_i, \sigma (i) (b_j, \phi(j) respectively) which is the sum over pairs of permutations of the product of two products, making it possible to choose j=\sigma(i) and replace \phi with \phi \cdot \sigma and have sum over permutations \sigma of sum over permutations \phi of products over i of a_i, \sigma (i) b_\sigma(i), \phi(i).

Comment: ....continues

On the other side det(AB) is the sum over permutations of the product over i of the sums over k of a_i,k b_k,\sigma(i), which is the sum over permutations of the sum over k1,...kn of the products of a_(1,k_1)b(k_1,\sigma(1))...a_(n,k_n)b(k_n,\sigma(n)), or, if K is a function from {1,...n} to {1,...n} (not necessarily biunivocal), the sum over permutations of the sum over all functions K:{1,...,n}-->{1,...,n} of products over i of a_i,K(i) b_K(i),\phi(i). So we have the same thing with the exception that K is not necessarily one-to-one.

Comment: ...continues

But all terms where K is not one-to-one erase with one another from the right.hand-side for if K(i)=K(j) the \tau=(i,j) induces by composition a bijection over the set of permutations \sigma that stabilize K (K \sigma =K) sending even ones into odd ones and viceversa, so that they all eliminate in the big sum, remaining the terms where K is a permutation.

Comment: Everything of course is up to sign. I forgot multiplying by -1 raised to the sign of \sigma or \phi, but it is just that what makes things erase and it works, if you check the formula, it is very striaghtforward

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Every matrix can be transformed to an uper triangular form. You can easily calculate the determinant of two uper triangular matrices and their product, and see that the equality holds.